# Cant connect with FTP on NetBeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, ftp

I try to connect with FTP to my server using NetBeans 8.

My problem is that I get this error:

```
Because NetBeans is running on Windows and JDK 7, you might be facing a problem with FTP operations. Ensure that Windows built-in firewall does not block JDK 7 binaries
```

I have googled this error and found this fixes:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201449

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2754804

http://www.nemesis.co.nz/2013/02/netbeans-jre7-and-windows-firewall/

None of them seems to work for me.
I have windows 7 home premium 64bit with java 7

- Firewall is off.
- I run the command in CMD as admin and got OK
- I run netbeans as admin

When I try to connect with FTP to my server with WinSCP its working fine.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using ftp in WinSCP (and not s/ftp or ftps)?

Comment: You right.. I needed to use sftp

Comment: Have you tried not using passive mode?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assumption is incorrect based on the inability to connect with FTP. That message is unlikely to be related to authentication or authorization or client as it tends to indicate a remote host not listening on a particular port (as FTP is not considered a secure protocol, many hosts now block it). Configure NetBeans to use sftp. Because, while I WinSCP supports plain (unencrypted) ftp, it is generally used to provide encrypted file transfer with the [SSH file transfer protocol protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol). Per the linked Wikipedia article,

> In computing, the SSH File Transfer Protocol (also Secure File Transfer Protocol, or SFTP) is a network protocol that provides file access, file transfer, and file management functionalities over any reliable data stream.

Answer (score 1):

- If nothing works , this will work

Check your operating System proxy settings, it is blocking your incoming connection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I just changed "Configure Proxy" to "No Proxy" and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, solved unselecting `Passive mode` checkbox in:

`Project properties / Run configuration /` click on `Manage...` button to open `Remote connection` panel, and deselect `Passive mode` checkbox (was checked by default).

Answer (score 0):

Update java to version 8 helped me with this problem today.